# Animating a Network in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, igraph, gganimate

Does anyone know of a way to visualize a network (from `igraph`) as it evolves (i.e., new connections are made)? I've looked on https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/network/ and searched online but haven't seen anything.

For example, if the network is:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("igraph")

net.bg <- sample_pa(20) 
V(net.bg)$size <- 8
V(net.bg)$label <- "" 
E(net.bg)$arrow.mode <- 0

net.bg.df <- igraph::as_data_frame(net.bg) 

net.bg.df <- net.bg.df %>%
  mutate(time_frame = 1:n())

l <- layout_randomly(net.bg)

plot(net.bg, layout=l)
```

Is there a way to transition the animation by the field `time_frame` similar to a normal plot animation like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(gapminder)
theme_set(theme_bw())

p <- ggplot(
  gapminder, 
  aes(x = gdpPercap, y=lifeExp, size = pop, colour = country)
) +
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE, alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_color_viridis_d() +
  scale_size(range = c(2, 12)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  labs(x = "GDP per capita", y = "Life expectancy")

p + transition_time(year) +
  labs(title = "Year: {frame_time}")
```

Comment: Just found `ndtv-d3` under the section `dynamic network visualisation` on this article : https://kateto.net/network-visualization. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ggraph` [package](https://www.data-imaginist.com/2017/ggraph-introduction-edges/), which can also be used together with `gganimate`and handles `igraph` objects well.

For this to work we need to specify the time points in which the edges should be active. This is not very elegantly done by creating a list of starting time and end points (which is the number rows in the original dataset).

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggraph)
library(gganimate)
df0 <- net.bg.df
df0$time_frame <- as.numeric(df0$time_frame)
for(i in 1:nrow(df0)){
  df0$time_frame[i] <- list(df0$time_frame[i][[1]]:19)
}
df <- unnest(df0, time_frame)
g2 <- graph_from_data_frame(df)

l <- as.data.frame(l)  # ggraph only accepts data.frame
colnames(l) <- c("x", "y") # ggraph needs these column names
ggraph(g2, layout = "manual", node.position = l) +
  geom_node_point(color = "blue", size =3) +
  geom_edge_link0(show.legend = F, width = 1) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  transition_states(time_frame) +
  ggtitle(paste0("time point: ", "{closest_state}"))
```

And the rest is plotting the network and using the `transition_states`- function. Here are [additional](https://gist.github.com/thomasp85/c8e22be4628e4420d4f66bcc6c88ac87) [sources](https://gist.github.com/noamross/5a648649a8f0a3c35e7b18da419ac8c7).

[image: appearing edges]